# C# ArrayList IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on asp.net mvc and i'm posting some data from one controller to another controller.

These are my two arraylist coming.

First one contains id's

```
-822602-822603-822604-822605-822607
```

Second contains values

```
-Ara Sınav-Ödev-Ödev-Ödev-Final
```

I Just want to split these values but i got null error second one.

This works

```
@{
string deger = Convert.ToString(ViewData["degerler"]);

int count = deger.Count(f => f == '-');

string[] ar = { "-" };

string ret = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string[] split = deger.Split(ar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    <li>@split[0]</li>

    deger = deger.Replace(split[0], "");
}
```

}

This give out of range error

```
@{
    string degerAd = Convert.ToString(ViewData["degerlerAd"]);

    int count2 = degerAd.Count(f => f == '-');

    string[] ar2 = { "-" };


    for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
    {
        string[] split2 = degerAd.Split(ar2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        <li>@split2[0]</li>

        degerAd = degerAd.Replace(split2[0], "");
    }
}
```

They are same, they all got data, but second one not work.

error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7cTs.png

Comment: can you post the error? Where are the arraylists defined? Have you set breakpoints to debug the error?

Comment: I have no error until i splitting theese lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
        string arr = "-Ara Sınav-Ödev-Ödev-Ödev-Final";
        string[] split = arr.TrimStart('-').Split('-');
        foreach (var item in split)
        {
            <li>item</li>
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this line:

```
degerAd = degerAd.Replace(split2[0], "");
```

After facing word "Ödev" string will become "-----Final" (3 occurrences will be replaced). To fix this `split2` declaration can be moved outside the cycle (not tested):

```
@{
    string degerAd = Convert.ToString(ViewData["degerlerAd"]);

    int count2 = degerAd.Count(f => f == '-');

    string[] ar2 = { "-" };
    string[] split2 = degerAd.Split(ar2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
    {
        <li>@split2[i]</li>
    }
}
```

If you want to have distinct values in `ul`, just use Linq method `Distinct`. Replace

```
string[] split2 = degerAd.Split(ar2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
{
    <li>@split2[i]</li>
}
```

with

```
IENumerable<string> split2 = degerAd.Split(ar2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct();

foreach (string el in split2)
{
    <li>@el</li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have to concentrate in the duplicates from the array.

If you replace some value means it will replace which are all like it, so their may cause more than one removal, so you have to count the duplicate count before removing. Please try like below.

```
@{
string degerAd = Convert.ToString(ViewData["degerlerAd"]);

int count2 = degerAd.Count(f => f == '-');

string[] ar2 = { "-" };


for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
{
    string[] split2 = degerAd.Split(ar2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int dupCount = 0;
    foreach (string s in split2)
    {
        if (s == split2[0])
        {
            dupCount += 1; 
        }

    }

    if(dupCount > 1)
    {
        dupCount = dupCount - 1;
        i = i + dupCount;
    }

    <li>@split2[0]</li>

    degerAd = degerAd.Replace(split2[0], "");
}
}
```